# Find common friends/interactions on array columns

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I have a DF estructured like this:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
                    'person_1': ['Frodo', 'Frodo', 'Gandalf']
                    ,'person_2': ['Sam', 'Legolas', 'Legolas']
                    ,'relations_person_1': [
                       ['Gandalf', 'Sam', 'Legolas', 'Gollum', 'Sauron'],
                       ['Gandalf', 'Sam', 'Legolas', 'Gollum', 'Sauron'],                        
                       ['Bilbo', 'Frodo', 'Sauron', 'Sam']
                      ]
                    ,'relations_person_2': [
                       ['Gandalf', 'Frodo', 'Gimli', 'Gollum'],
                       ['Galadriel', 'Arwen', 'Gimli', 'Frodo'],
                       ['Galadriel', 'Arwen', 'Gimli', 'Frodo'],
                      ]
                    })
```

Where `relations_person_1` and `relations_person_2` are relations of `person_1` and `person_2` respectively.
I need to find the common names between the relations of "person_1" and "person_2".

I managed to solve this with the following code

```
test['common_friends'] = test.apply(
    lambda x: np.intersect1d(x.relations_person_1 ,x.relations_person_2)
   ,axis = 1)

test.head()
#output:
    person_1    person_2    relations_person_1                      relations_person_2                  common_friends
0   Frodo       Sam         [Gandalf, Sam, Legolas, Gollum, Sauron] [Gandalf, Frodo, Gimli, Gollum]     [Gandalf, Gollum]
1   Frodo       Legolas     [Gandalf, Sam, Legolas, Gollum, Sauron] [Galadriel, Arwen, Gimli, Frodo]    []
2   Gandalf     Legolas     [Bilbo, Frodo, Sauron, Sam]             [Galadriel, Arwen, Gimli, Frodo]    [Frodo]
```

My problem with my solution is the use of `apply`, which has been very slow when used throughout DF. I wonder if there would be a more optimized way to get the result, maybe avoiding the use of `apply` or using some graph structure in the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` is inherently slower in `pandas`, instead of using `apply` we can `zip` the columns then inside a list comprehension test for the membership of `relations_person_1` in `relations_person_2` using `set` intersection

```
test['common_friends'] = [list(set(x).intersection(y)) for x, y in 
                          zip(test['relations_person_1'], test['relations_person_2'])]
```

Result

```
  person_1 person_2                       relations_person_1                relations_person_2     common_friends
0    Frodo      Sam  [Gandalf, Sam, Legolas, Gollum, Sauron]   [Gandalf, Frodo, Gimli, Gollum]  [Gollum, Gandalf]
1    Frodo  Legolas  [Gandalf, Sam, Legolas, Gollum, Sauron]  [Galadriel, Arwen, Gimli, Frodo]                 []
2  Gandalf  Legolas              [Bilbo, Frodo, Sauron, Sam]  [Galadriel, Arwen, Gimli, Frodo]            [Frodo]
```

**Timings** for reference

```
# Sample dataframe with 300000 rows generated for testing purpose
test = pd.concat([test] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

%%timeit
_ = [list(set(x).intersection(y)) for x, y in zip(test['relations_person_1'], test['relations_person_2'])]
# 262 ms ± 34.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


%%timeit
_ = test.apply(
    lambda x: np.intersect1d(x.relations_person_1 ,x.relations_person_2)
   ,axis = 1)
# 19.3 s ± 1.51 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Simply avoiding `apply` and using list comprehension and `set` intersection we can gain a performance boost of around `73x`

Answer (score 1):

I would go a different route, by representing the relations differently.
I’m assuming this is the dataframe you originally start with:

```
>>> df
    person                         relations_person
0    Frodo  [Gandalf, Sam, Legolas, Gollum, Sauron]
1  Gandalf              [Bilbo, Frodo, Sauron, Sam]
2      Sam          [Gandalf, Frodo, Gimli, Gollum]
3  Legolas         [Galadriel, Arwen, Gimli, Frodo]
```

If not you can always use:

```
>>> df = pd.concat([
...   test[['person' + suffix, 'relations_person' + suffix]]\
...   .rename(columns=lambda c: c.replace(suffix, ''))
...   for suffix in ('_1', '_2')
... ]).drop_duplicates('person').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then using `explode` create all pairs of interactions:

```
>>> relations = df.explode('relations_person')
>>> relations
     person relations_person
0     Frodo          Gandalf
1     Frodo              Sam
2     Frodo          Legolas
3     Frodo           Gollum
4     Frodo           Sauron
5   Gandalf            Bilbo
6   Gandalf            Frodo
7   Gandalf           Sauron
8   Gandalf              Sam
9       Sam          Gandalf
10      Sam            Frodo
11      Sam            Gimli
12      Sam           Gollum
13  Legolas        Galadriel
14  Legolas            Arwen
15  Legolas            Gimli
16  Legolas            Frodo
```

To get the relations in a similar format so we can do a simple merge, we `stack` the columns:

```
>>> lookup = test[['person_1', 'person_2']].stack().to_frame('person').rename_axis(['row', 'col'])
>>> lookup
               person
row col              
0   person_1    Frodo
    person_2      Sam
1   person_1    Frodo
    person_2  Legolas
2   person_1  Gandalf
    person_2  Legolas
```

Now it’s easy to generate all the relations:

```
>>> common = lookup.reset_index().merge(relations, how='left', on='person')
>>> common
        row       col   person relations_person
0         0  person_1    Frodo          Gandalf
1         0  person_1    Frodo              Sam
2         0  person_1    Frodo          Legolas
3         0  person_1    Frodo           Gollum
4         0  person_1    Frodo           Sauron
5         0  person_2      Sam          Gandalf
6         0  person_2      Sam            Frodo
7         0  person_2      Sam            Gimli
8         0  person_2      Sam           Gollum
9         1  person_1    Frodo          Gandalf
10        1  person_1    Frodo              Sam
11        1  person_1    Frodo          Legolas
12        1  person_1    Frodo           Gollum
13        1  person_1    Frodo           Sauron
14        1  person_2  Legolas        Galadriel
15        1  person_2  Legolas            Arwen
16        1  person_2  Legolas            Gimli
17        1  person_2  Legolas            Frodo
18        2  person_1  Gandalf            Bilbo
19        2  person_1  Gandalf            Frodo
20        2  person_1  Gandalf           Sauron
21        2  person_1  Gandalf              Sam
22        2  person_2  Legolas        Galadriel
23        2  person_2  Legolas            Arwen
24        2  person_2  Legolas            Gimli
25        2  person_2  Legolas            Frodo
```

From there the number of times each relation appears in a row of the `test` dataframe:

```
>>> relation_counts = common.groupby('row')['relations_person'].value_counts()
>>> relation_counts
row      relations_person
0        Gandalf             2
         Gollum              2
         Frodo               1
         Gimli               1
         Legolas             1
         Sam                 1
         Sauron              1
1        Arwen               1
         Frodo               1
         Galadriel           1
         Gandalf             1
         Gimli               1
         Gollum              1
         Legolas             1
         Sam                 1
         Sauron              1
2        Frodo               2
         Arwen               1
         Bilbo               1
         Galadriel           1
         Gimli               1
         Sam                 1
         Sauron              1
```

And finally make lists from the entries that appear at least twice per row:

```
>>> test.join(relation_counts[relation_counts >= 2].groupby('row').agg(list).reindex(test.index, fill_value=[]))
  person_1 person_2                       relations_person_1                relations_person_2 relations_person
0    Frodo      Sam  [Gandalf, Sam, Legolas, Gollum, Sauron]   [Gandalf, Frodo, Gimli, Gollum]           [2, 2]
1    Frodo  Legolas  [Gandalf, Sam, Legolas, Gollum, Sauron]  [Galadriel, Arwen, Gimli, Frodo]               []
2  Gandalf  Legolas              [Bilbo, Frodo, Sauron, Sam]  [Galadriel, Arwen, Gimli, Frodo]              [2]
```

So in a condensed form:

```
relcounts = test[['person_1', 'person_2']].stack().rename('person').reset_index()\
  .merge(df.explode('relations_person'), on='person', how='left')\
  .groupby('level_0')['relations_person'].value_counts()
test.join(relcounts[relcounts > 1].groupby(level=0).agg(list))
```

Comment: unfortunately the code ran slowly in the `apply` command, just like mine

Comment: There you go @Terry if you have the opportunity to test this it should be way better than my previous version. Kinda tough to test how it runs without a big dataset though,

Comment: Hello mate, sorry for the delay in retesting the code. Your proposal reduce the execution time to 14 seconds (vs. 28 seconds with my `apply` and 600 milliseconds with @Shubham Sharma's proposal :)